# Module is isomorphic to a direct sum of modules, then the length(M)=sum length(M_i)

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Is there any proof (or even a counterexample) for:

If $M\tilde{=} M_1\oplus ... \oplus M_n$, then it follows for the finite length $l(M) = l(M_1)+...+l(M_n)$. (Modules of a commutative ring with unity)

Comment: This follows directly from the definition of length by choosing a composition series for each summand.

Comment: I was really sure, that this Lemma ist right. But I can't even figure it out (right now), how to "choose" (axiom of choice allways right in commutative algebra?) a composition series.

Comment: Let us consider an example: $R=\mathbb{Z}, M=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is given by primefactorisation $n=\prod\limits_{k=1}^r p_k$. (Where the $p_k$ are not distinct at all), then $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \tilde{=} \bigoplus\limits_{k=1}^r \mathbb{Z}/p_k\mathbb{Z}$.

I know (and I'm able to prove), that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} = 1$ for any prime p. So, how do I choose the composition series right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the simpler case where $n=2$.

> If $M_1$ and $M_2$ have finite length, then also $M_1\oplus M_2$ has finite length.

Let $0=X_0<X_1<X_2<\dots<X_h=M_1$ and $0=Y_0<Y_1<Y_2<\dots<Y_k=M_2$ be composition series. Then
$$
0=X_0\oplus0<X_1\oplus0<\dots<X_h\oplus 0
<X_n\oplus Y_1<X_n\oplus Y_2<\dots<X_h\oplus Y_k=M_1\oplus M_2
$$
is a composition series for $M_1\oplus M_2$ of length $h+k=l(M_1)+l(M_2)$

Now suppose the result holds for $n$ modules, $n\ge1$; then
$$
M_1\oplus\dots\oplus M_n\oplus M_{n+1}
=
(M_1\oplus\dots\oplus M_n)\oplus M_{n+1}
$$
so, by the simpler case above,
$$
l(M_1\oplus\dots\oplus M_n\oplus M_{n+1})=
l(M_1\oplus\dots\oplus M_n)+l(M_{n+1})
$$
and the induction hypothesis allows to conclude.

Comment: You're so right. Thank you!